# Is there a way to configure the ClientBuilder POST request that would enable it to receive both a return code AND a JSON object?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, weblogic12c

***Assume "postWS" calling  "postRespWS"...***

"postWS"s GET method (non-SpringMVC) utilizes JAX-RS "ClientBuilder" to issue a call to the POST method in "postRespWS" (SpringMVC)   ...

(NOTE: "postRespWS"'s POST method should return both a return code *and* a JSON object)

***PROBLEM:*** In response to the POST call, "postWS" receives back a successful return code (i.e., "200") - but, ***NOT*** the expected JSON object...

-i.e., the response does NOT include the following JSON object...

```
    {
        "entryAToList": [
        {
            "errorCode": "100",
            "errorMessage": "blah...blah...blah...",
            "entryNumber": "ITEM0000AX",
            "accepted": true
        },
        {
            "errorCode": "200",
            "errorMessage": "blah...blah...blah...",
            "entryNumber": "ITEM0000BX",
            "accepted": true
        },
        {
            "errorCode": "300",
            "errorMessage": "blah...blah...blah...",
            "entryNumber": "ITEM0000CX",
            "accepted": true
        }
        ],
        "entryBToList": [
        {
            "errorCode": "101",
            "errorMessage": "bleah...bleah...bleah...",
            "entryNumber": "ITEM0000AZ",
            "accepted": false
        },
        {
            "errorCode": "201",
            "errorMessage": "bleah...bleah...bleah...",
            "entryNumber": "ITEM0000BZ",
            "accepted": false
        },
        {
            "errorCode": "301",
            "errorMessage": "bleah...bleah...bleah...",
            "entryNumber": "ITEM0000CZ",
            "accepted": false
        }
        ]
    }
```

***QUESTION:***
Is there a way to configure the ClientBuilder in "postWS"s POST request that would enable it to receive both the return code *and* the JSON object - i.e., returned by "postRespWS"?

***MORE DETAILED NOTES, BELOW...***

---

***"postWS"'s GET method looks like this...***

```
    package aaa.bbb.ccc.ws;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.*;
    import javax.ws.rs.*;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

    @Stateless
    @Path("/postservice")
    public class PostService {
        -
        -
        -
        @GET
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
        public PostRespDTO get() {

            //curl -v -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"entryAList\":[\"ITEM0000A\",\"ITEM0000B\",\"ITEM0000C\"],\"entryBList\":[\"AAA\",\"BBB\",\"CCC\"]}" http://localhost:7001/postRespWS/postrespservice

            // {
            //   "entryAList":["ITEM0000A","ITEM0000B","ITEM0000C"],
            //   "entryBList":["AAA","BBB","CCC"]
            // }            

            PostDTO postDTO = new PostDTO();
            postDTO.setEntryAList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("ITEM0000A","ITEM0000B","ITEM0000C")));
            postDTO.setEntryBList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")));
            PostRespDTO prd = new PostRespDTO();
            try {
                Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
                WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:7001/postRespWS/postrespservice");
                prd = target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(postDTO, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), PostRespDTO.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("________99__________get()__________________e.getMessage()=" + e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            //...NOTE: "prd" does not contain the expected JSON object that is returned by "postRespWS"...
            return prd;
        }
        -
        -
        -
    }
```

***"postRespWS"'s POST (Spring MVC - based) method looks like this (NOTE: the code in this method cannot be modified)...***

```
    package aaa.bbb.ccc.ws;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

    @Controller
    public class PostRespService {
        -
        -
        -
        @RequestMapping(value = {"/postrespservice"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public PostRespDTO post(@RequestBody PostDTO postDTO) {    
            PostRespDTO postRespDTO = new PostRespDTO();

            if (postDTO != null && postDTO.getEntryAList() != null) {
                try {
                List<PostRespDetailA> nonDeletedList = new ArrayList<>();
                List<PostRespDetailA> deletedList = new ArrayList<>();                
                PostRespDetailA prda = new PostRespDetailA();
                int i = 100;
                for (String s : postDTO.getEntryAList()) {
                    prda = new PostRespDetailA();
                    prda.setErrorCode(String.valueOf(i));
                    prda.setErrorMessage("blah...blah...blah...");
                    prda.setEntryNumber(s+"X");
                    prda.setAccepted(true);
                    deletedList.add(prda);
                    prda = new PostRespDetailA();
                    prda.setErrorCode(String.valueOf(i + 1));
                    prda.setErrorMessage("bleah...bleah...bleah...");
                    prda.setEntryNumber(s+"Z");
                    prda.setAccepted(false);
                    nonDeletedList.add(prda);  //adding to both - just for testing...
                    i+=100;
                }
                postRespDTO.getEntryAToList().addAll(deletedList);
                postRespDTO.getEntryBToList().addAll(nonDeletedList);                

                } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("________________________removeEntryFromStmt________________________Exception - e.getMessage()=" + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }

            return postRespDTO;      
        }  
        -
        -
        -
    }
```

*** PostDTO.java ***

```
            package aaa.bbb.ccc.ws;

            import java.io.Serializable;
            import java.util.List;

            public class PostDTO {
                private List<String> entryAList;
                private List<String> entryBList;
                public List<String> getEntryAList() {
                    return entryAList;
                }
                public void setEntryAList(List<String> entryAList) {
                    this.entryAList = entryAList;
                }
                public List<String> getEntryBList() {
                    return entryBList;
                }
                public void setEntryBList(List<String> entryBList) {
                    this.entryBList = entryBList;
                }
            }
```

*** PostRespDTO ***

```
            package aaa.bbb.ccc.ws;

            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;

            public class PostRespDTO {
                private List<PostRespDetailA> entryAToList;
                private List<PostRespDetailA> entryBToList;
                public List<PostRespDetailA> getEntryAToList() {
                    if (null == entryAToList) {
                        entryAToList = new ArrayList<>();
                    }
                    return entryAToList;
                }
                public List<PostRespDetailA> getEntryBToList() {
                    if (null == entryBToList) {
                        entryBToList = new ArrayList<>();
                    }
                    return entryBToList;
                }
            }
```

*** PostRespDetailA.java ***

```
            package aaa.bbb.ccc.ws;

            public class PostRespDetailA {

                private boolean isAccepted;
                private String errorCode;
                private String errorMessage;
                private String entryNumber;

                public void setAccepted(boolean accepted){
                    this.isAccepted = accepted;
                }
                public boolean isAccepted(){
                    return this.isAccepted;
                }

                public void setErrorCode(String errorCode){
                    this.errorCode = errorCode;
                }
                public String getErrorCode(){
                    return this.errorCode;
                }

                public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage){
                    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
                }
                public String getErrorMessage(){
                    return this.errorMessage;
                }

                public String getEntryNumber(){
                    return entryNumber;
                }
                public void setEntryNumber(String entryNumnber){
                    this.entryNumber = entryNumnber;
                }
            }
```

*** PostRespDetailB.java ***

```
            package aaa.bbb.ccc.ws;

            import aaa.bbb.ccc.ws.WSConstants.WSEnum;

            public class PostRespDetailB {

                private String entryNumnber;
                private WSEnum wsEnum;

                public PostRespDetailB(String entryNumnber, WSEnum wsEnum) {
                    this.entryNumnber = entryNumnber;
                    this.wsEnum = null; //wsEnum;
                }

                public String getEntryNumnber() {
                    return entryNumnber;
                }
                public void setEntryNumnber(String entryNumnber) {
                    this.entryNumnber = entryNumnber;
                }

                public WSEnum getWSEnum() {
                    return wsEnum;
                }
                public void setWSEnum(WSEnum wsEnum) {
                    this.wsEnum = wsEnum;
                }
            }
```

***A test call to "postWS", looks like this...***

```
    $ curl -v -k -X GET http://10.162.188.159:7001/postWS/resources/postservice
```

***The output looks like this...***

```
    $ curl -v -k -X GET http://localhost:7001/postWS/resources/postservice
    * STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x80047810; line 1034 (connection #-5000)
    * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    *   Trying ::1...
    * STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x80047810; line 1087 (connection #0)
    * Connected to localhost (::1) port 7001 (#0)
    * STATE: WAITCONNECT => DO handle 0x80047810; line 1233 (connection #0)
    > GET /postWS/resources/postservice HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
    > Host: localhost:7001
    > Accept: */*
    >
    * STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x80047810; line 1319 (connection #0)
    * STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x80047810; line 1445 (connection #0)
    * STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x80047810; line 1458 (connection #0)
    * HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Date: Thu, 21 Jan 2016 19:56:20 GMT
    < Content-Length: 2
    < Content-Type: application/json
    <
    * STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x80047810; line 1628 (connection #0)
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
    * Expire cleared
    {}
```

***A test call to "postRespWS" directly, looks like this...***

```
    curl -v -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"entryAList\":[\"ITEM0000A\",\"ITEM0000B\",\"ITEM0000C\"],\"entryBList\":[\"AAA\",\"BBB\",\"CCC\"]}" http://localhost:7001/postRespWS/postrespservice
```

***The output looks like this...***

```
    $ curl -v -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"entryAList\":[\"ITEM0000A\",\"ITEM0000B\",\"ITEM0000C\"],\"entryBList\":[\"AAA\",\"BBB\",\"CCC\"]}" http://localhost:7001/postRespWS/postrespservice
    * STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x80047810; line 1034 (connection #-5000)
    * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    *   Trying ::1...
    * STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x80047810; line 1087 (connection #0)
    * Connected to localhost (::1) port 7001 (#0)
    * STATE: WAITCONNECT => DO handle 0x80047810; line 1233 (connection #0)
    > POST /postRespWS/postrespservice HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
    > Host: localhost:7001
    > Accept: */*
    > Content-Type: application/json
    > Content-Length: 85
    >
    * upload completely sent off: 85 out of 85 bytes
    * STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x80047810; line 1319 (connection #0)
    * STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x80047810; line 1445 (connection #0)
    * STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x80047810; line 1458 (connection #0)
    * HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Date: Thu, 21 Jan 2016 20:40:27 GMT
    < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    < Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    <
    * STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x80047810; line 1628 (connection #0)
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
    * Expire cleared
    {"entryAToList":[{"errorCode":"100","errorMessage":"blah...blah...blah...","entryNumber":"ITEM0000AX","accepted":true},{"errorCode":"200","errorMessage":"blah...blah...blah...","entryNumber":"ITEM0000BX","accepted":true},{"errorCode":"300","errorMessage":"blah...blah...blah...","entryNumber":"ITEM0000CX","accepted":true}],"entryBToList":[{"errorCode":"101","errorMessage":"bleah...bleah...bleah...","entryNumber":"ITEM0000AZ","accepted":false},{"errorCode":"201","errorMessage":"bleah...bleah...bleah...","entryNumber":"ITEM0000BZ","accepted":false},{"errorCode":"301","errorMessage":"bleah...bleah...bleah...","entryNumber":"ITEM0000CZ","accepted":false}]}
```

Notice how a direct call to this POST method returns both the return code (200) *and* the JSON object...
- is there a way to configure the ClientBuilder in "postWS" to obtain the same result???

Environment: Java 7,  WebLogic 12.1.3 w/ "jax-rs(2.0,2.5.1)" deployable library

***"postWS"'s pom.xml***

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>postWS</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>postWS</name>
        <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
        <!-- You need this for Java EE support... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0-rc1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>    
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

***"postRespWS"'s pom.xml***

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
        <artifactId>postRespWS</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>

        <name>postRespWS</name>

        <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>      

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>  
            <version>2.5</version>  
        </dependency>                     

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>  
            <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>  
        </dependency>

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
            <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>  
        </dependency>

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>  
            <version>2.4.1</version>  
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>    
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

Thanks for your help!!

P.S.

Also, I noticed, that...

...when post is called directly using "curl" and JSON object is returned ...

```
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

...when post is called via "postWS" (using ClientBuilfer) and JSON object is not returned...

```
    Content-Length: 2
    Content-Type: application/json
```

---

Per a recent suggestion, I've modified the client code as follows...

```
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:7001/postRespWS/postrespservice");
        Response response = target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(postDTO, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        prd = response.readEntity(PostRespDTO.class);
        int status = response.getStatus();
```

...However, there is no change in the result...  I.e., I receive a response code ("200"), but, am unable to see/access the JSON object.

---

The only way I've managed to receive back both the response code *and* JSON object is to utilize an "older" technique (not using ClientBuilder)... 
(not certain what to infer from this, yet).  -Also, re-configured WebLogic with the default jax-rs version, rather than the deployable jax-rs(2.0/2.5) running lib.

Changes to the pom.xml:

```
    -
    -
    -
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>          
    -
    -
    -
```

Changes to the code...

```
    package aaa.bbb.ccc.ws;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    @Stateless
    @Path("/postservice")
    public class PostService {

        private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger("PostService");

        public PostService() {
        }

        @GET
        //@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})    
        public PostRespDTO get() {

        PostDTO postDTO = new PostDTO();
        postDTO.setEntryAList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("ITEM0000A", "ITEM0000B", "ITEM0000C")));
        postDTO.setEntryBList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")));
        PostRespDTO prd = new PostRespDTO();
        try {
            ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
            clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
            Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
            WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:7001/postRespWS/postrespservice");
            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, postDTO);
            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
            }
            prd = response.getEntity(PostRespDTO.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("__________________get()__________________e.getMessage()=" + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return prd;
        }
    }
```

Output (using curl) looks like this...

```
    $ curl -v -k -X GET -HAccept:application/json http://localhost:7001/postWS/resources/postservice
    * STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x80047810; line 1034 (connection #-5000)
    * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    *   Trying ::1...
    * STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x80047810; line 1087 (connection #0)
    * Connected to localhost (::1) port 7001 (#0)
    * STATE: WAITCONNECT => DO handle 0x80047810; line 1233 (connection #0)
    > GET /postWS/resources/postservice HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
    > Host: localhost:7001
    > Accept:application/json
    >
    * STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x80047810; line 1319 (connection #0)
    * STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x80047810; line 1445 (connection #0)
    * STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x80047810; line 1458 (connection #0)
    * HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 22:56:54 GMT
    < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    < Content-Type: application/json
    <
    * STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x80047810; line 1628 (connection #0)
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
    {"entryAToList":[{"errorCode":"100","errorMessage":"blah...blah...blah...","entryNumber":"ITEM0000AX","accepted":true},{"errorCode":"200","errorMessage":"blah...blah...blah...","entryNumber":"ITEM0000BX","accepted":true},{"errorCode":"300","errorMessage":"blah...blah...blah...","entryNumber":"ITEM0000CX","accepted":true}],"entryBToList":[{"errorCode":"101","errorMessage":"bleah...bleah...bleah...","entryNumber":"ITEM0000AZ","accepted":false},{"errorCode":"201","errorMessage":"bleah...bleah...bleah...","entryNumber":"ITEM0000BZ","accepted":false},{"errorCode":"301","errorMessage":"bleah...bleah...bleah...","entryNumber":"ITEM0000CZ","accepted":false}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the response, see [SyncInvoker#post(Entity)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#post-javax.ws.rs.client.Entity-):

> Invoke HTTP POST method for the current request synchronously.
>
> **Returns:**
>   invocation response.

and you can get the entity from the response, see [Response#readEntity(Class)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-):

> Read the message entity input stream as an instance of specified Java type using a `MessageBodyReader` that supports mapping the message entity stream onto the requested type.

but you need to register a provider for JSON, see [Configurable#register(Class)](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Configurable.html#register(java.lang.Class)):

> Register a class of a custom JAX-RS component (such as an extension provider or a `feature` meta-provider) to be instantiated and used in the scope of this configurable context.

The right provider depends on JAX-RS implementation ([Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html), [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html), Resteasy,...), model implementation (POJO, JAX-B, ...), content type (JSON, XML, text, ...) and processor implementation ([Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome), [JSON-P](https://jsonp.java.net/), [Jettison](https://github.com/codehaus/jettison), ...)

Your modified example:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(providerClass).build();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:7001/postRespWS/postrespservice");
Response response = target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(postDTO, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
prd = response.readEntity(PostRespDTO.class);
int status = response.getStatus();
```

Also be sure, that your `PostRespDTO` complies with [Java Bean conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions), containing getter and setter methods.

Comment: thx, dur.  adding a missing setter makes it all work.  Again, I wonder why the old-style call is unaffected by the missing getter... Is it a change in spec/standard in the new JAX-RS[?]....